# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str from JSON file

Tags: python, json

Below is a snippet from the code that I have.

```
            fullsrcurl = self.srcjson + format_type + '&jobname=' + joburl
            srcfile = urllib2.urlopen(fullsrcurl)
            if self.format_export == 'json':
                srcdata = json.load(srcfile)
                pprint(srcdata)
                srcjobmst_id =  srcdata["jobmst_id"][0]
```

What I'm trying to do with the above code is read from an API url that's returning json and get the 'jobmst_id' value from that json.  The pprint(srcdata is providing the json below) from there I want to pull just the jobmst_id value which in the case below would be '58908'.  I'll happily take it as an integer it can be converted, but as it stands right now it fails on the line with the error in the subject.

Below is the json -

```
[{u'evntmst_id': {u'evntmst_calendar': 0,
                  u'evntmst_crttm': u'2009-12-04T11:22:03',
                  u'evntmst_desc': None,
                  u'evntmst_fiscal': 0,
                  u'evntmst_frcstdt': u'2012-12-31T00:00:00',
                  u'evntmst_freq': 1,
                  u'evntmst_fromdt': None,
                  u'evntmst_id': 1,
                  u'evntmst_intsect': u'N',
                  u'evntmst_lstchgtm': u'2009-12-04T12:28:52',
                  u'evntmst_lstcmptm': u'2014-08-28T12:00:29',
                  u'evntmst_monthdays': u'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
                  u'evntmst_months': u'YYYYYYYYYYYY',
                  u'evntmst_name': u'Daily
                 ',
                  u'evntmst_occur': 0,
                  u'evntmst_offset': 0,
                  u'evntmst_owner': 2,
                  u'evntmst_public': u'Y',
                  u'evntmst_subtype': None,
                  u'evntmst_timeframe': 0,
                  u'evntmst_totcnt': None,
                  u'evntmst_type': 2,
                  u'evntmst_untildt': u'2012-12-31T00:00:00',
                  u'evntmst_weekdays': u'YYYYYYY',
                  u'evntmst_weeks': u'NNNNN'},
  u'job_dependencies': [],
  u'job_events': [],
  u'jobcls_id': None,
  u'jobdtl_id': {u'jobdtl_abrtonclderr': None,
                 u'jobdtl_allowadhoc': u'Y',
                 u'jobdtl_carryover': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_cmd': None,
                 u'jobdtl_concur': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_deplogic': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_deprerun': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_duration': 67,
                 u'jobdtl_envfile': None,
                 u'jobdtl_estdurexclude': 4,
                 u'jobdtl_estmethod': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_extinfo': None,
                 u'jobdtl_failalarm': None,
                 u'jobdtl_fromdt': u'2012-11-22T00:00:00',
                 u'jobdtl_fromtm': u'1899-12-30T23:30:00',
                 u'jobdtl_id': 58908,
                 u'jobdtl_inhagent': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_inhevent': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_inhoptions': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_inhrepeat': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_inhtime': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_interval': None,
                 u'jobdtl_intervalcnt': None,
                 u'jobdtl_maxrun': 60,
                 u'jobdtl_minrun': 60,
                 u'jobdtl_nearoutage': 3,
                 u'jobdtl_normalexit': 0,
                 u'jobdtl_normalop': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_normalrange': 0,
                 u'jobdtl_outputname': None,
                 u'jobdtl_params': None,
                 u'jobdtl_priority': 50,
                 u'jobdtl_proxy': 4,
                 u'jobdtl_proxy2': None,
                 u'jobdtl_psjob': None,
                 u'jobdtl_rerun': None,
                 u'jobdtl_rerunok': u'Y',
                 u'jobdtl_retnsn': 30,
                 u'jobdtl_sapcount': None,
                 u'jobdtl_savelogonly': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_saveoutput': u'Y',
                 u'jobdtl_statuscl': None,
                 u'jobdtl_timewin': 2,
                 u'jobdtl_trackcl': None,
                 u'jobdtl_trackcmd': None,
                 u'jobdtl_trackmethod': 1,
                 u'jobdtl_trxid': None,
                 u'jobdtl_unit': None,
                 u'jobdtl_untildt': u'1899-12-30T00:00:00',
                 u'jobdtl_untiltm': u'1899-12-30T23:50:00',
                 u'jobdtl_waitop': u'N',
                 u'jobdtl_workdir': None,
                 u'nodlstmst_id': 27,
                 u'nodmst_id': None,
                 u'servicemst_id': None},
  u'jobmst_active': u'Y',
  u'jobmst_alias': u'58908     ',
  u'jobmst_crttm': u'2012-11-22T12:22:59',
  u'jobmst_desc': None,
  u'jobmst_dirty': u' ',
  u'jobmst_evntoffset': None,
  u'jobmst_id': 58908,
  u'jobmst_lstchgtm': u'2012-11-22T13:01:34',
  u'jobmst_mode': 0,
  u'jobmst_name': u'SWIFT DB Backup',
  u'jobmst_owner': {u'owner_allagents': u'Y',
                    u'owner_id': 257,
                    u'owner_name': u'Common                        ',
                    u'owner_type': 2},
  u'jobmst_prntid': None,
  u'jobmst_prntname': None,
  u'jobmst_type': 1,
  u'runbook_url': None}]
```

Comment: You're not including the start of the JSON, because there must be a starting } and ] for it to be valid. And that answers your question: it comes back as a list with a dictionary in it, not just a dictionary. You wanted to do `srcdata[0]["jobmst_id"]`, not `jobmst_id["jobmst_id"][0]`.

Comment: The json is valid.  I updated the full file.  I had to trim it because it was complaining about too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to retrieve the data is `srcdata[0]["jobmst_id"]` and not `srcdata["jobmst_id"][0]`.